# How to force curly brace in android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to set up android studio to a coding standard and I cannot get one setting in particular.

I would like for there to always be curly braces on if statements (including one line ones) on manually typed and generated ones. I am using Kotlin in android studio

what it does:

```
if(true)
   foo
```

what I want :

```
if(true){
   bar
}
```

Comment: File->Settings->Coding Style->Java there you can find all coding settings

Comment: @Jasurbek please read "... using Kotlin ..." . How to do it there ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enforce specific code style rules, you might consider using a code analysis or linting tool. One such popular tool is `ktlint`, which can help enforce code style guidelines, including the placement of curly braces, in Kotlin projects.

To use ktlint with Android Studio you have 2 approaches either using ktlint extension or install the wrapper plugin.

##### approach #1

1. Open your project in Android Studio.
2. Install the ktlint plugin for Android Studio. To do this, go to "Preferences" (or "Settings") > "Plugins," search for "ktlint," and click on "Install."
3. In the root directory of your project, create a file named `.editorconfig` if it doesn't exist already.
4. Add the following configuration to the `.editorconfig` file to enforce placing curly braces:

```
[*.{kt, kts}]
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
brace_style = end_of_line

// follow ktlint standard rules for android studio
ktlint_code_style=android_studio
// follow ktlint standard rules for intellij idea
ktlint_code_style= intellij_idea
```

---

##### approach #2

Another way to use the package is installing it using gradle.

1. install ktlint wrapper plugin [docs](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint)
2. Add checks in gradle:app

```
// format the code prior each build
tasks.getByPath("preBuild").dependsOn("ktlintFormat")

// custom rules
ktlint {
    android = true
    ignoreFailures = false
    disabledRules = ["final-newline"]
    reporters {
        reporter "plain"
        reporter "checkstyle"
    }
}
```

In case you have a pipeline or hooks you can execute the below commands for reformatting and checking.

```bash
./gradlew ktlintFormat
./gradlew ktlintCheck
```

For checking all kind of options you can execute the below:

```bash
./gradlew ktlint
```

##### references

- for visualization refer to this [video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSgPNbEcX98&ab_channel=PhilippLackner) or [video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIzgFkpbWRA&ab_channel=AndroidDeveloper)
- for more details check [ktlint official docs](https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/0.49.1/rules/code-styles/)

Comment: I've installed the plug-in and added the .editorconfig file to the project root with

```
[*.{kt,kts}]
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
# Place opening brace on the same line as the declaration
brace_style = end_of_line
```

It's still not forcing braces (or putting braces on reformat). Can you check again, please?

Comment: Hi @CyberAvater ; make sure you restarted AS after installing the pkg and it's enabled. you can check by clicking right at any syntax > refactor > reformat with ktlint. If ktlint is exist this means it's been installed successfully.

for auto-save go to settings > tools > actions on save, then enable [Reformat code, Optimize imports, Rearrange code].

besides this you can install the package using gradle and implement pipeline, pre-hooks, post-hooks and autofix before build.

Comment: @CyberAvater I updated my answer to include another approach.

Comment: I'm getting The property is not supported for brace_style and ktlint_code_style

Comment: ensure you put these configuration in .editorconfig not in gradle.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6uKGqgU

Comment: I've upvoted this answer, as this answer showed effort, but I wasn't able to get the expected result, ie if should drop with braces. so I cannot select it as the bounty winner.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the available styles by going to **Editor > Code Style > Kotlin**

[image]

Comment: I can see that. However, you didn't mention which settings give what OP is asking for.